# Cant zoom when multiple images in array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a `UIScrollview` for paging and zooming images, it is zooming fine when i have a single image in my array, else zooming behaves in a weird manner. Paging is fine. I am struggling with this for some days, please help some one. I am not familiar with `UIScrollview`. Thanks.

```
    -(void) settingScroll{
        int xx,yy,im_xx,im_yy,im_Wt,im_ht;

            CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
            xx      = screenRect.size.width;
            yy      = 452;
            im_xx   = 0;
            im_yy   = 0;
            im_Wt   = screenRect.size.width;
            im_ht   = 452;


            scxx =0;

            for(int i=0;i<[totalArray_menu count];i++)
            {
                scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scxx, 0, xx, yy)];

               [img2 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",initial_server_address,[totalArray_menu objectAtIndex:i]]]];

                img2.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightTextColor];
                [scroll addSubview:img2];
                [self.popUpImageScrollView2 addSubview: scroll];
                scxx+=xx;
            }

        cntSizX=scxx;
        self.popUpImageScrollView2.tag = 456;
        self.popUpImageScrollView2.contentSize        = CGSizeMake(cntSizX,yy);

        self.popUpImageScrollView2.backgroundColor    = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.popUpImageScrollView2.pagingEnabled      = YES;

        self.popUpImageScrollView2.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        self.popUpImageScrollView2.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

        self.popUpImageScrollView2.bounces=YES;
        scxx=xx;
        [self.popUpImageScrollView2 setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scxx*tag,0) animated:NO];
        [self.popUpImageView2 addSubview:self.popUpImageScrollView2];
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return scroll;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollV withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(double)scale
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    [self.popUpImageScrollView2 setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scale*screenRect.size.width, scale*452)];
}
```

Comment: can you add a screenshot of what is happening?

Comment: @HariHaraSudhan:image link here: http://tinypic.com/r/25p5l3k/8
Don't know it'll help you or not.